# Is there a way to do this in SQL (using a loop) or easier in R?

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, loops

I hope someone can help me with this head scratcher!

I have a data table about journeys which shows a person ID and the datetime they are seen at a stage of a route:

```
ID     |  Datetime            |   Routestage   
------ | -------------------- | ------------   
1234   | 12/10/16  10:20:00   | A          
1234   | 12/10/16  10:21:22   | B          
1234   | 12/10/16  10:23:34   | C          
1234   | 12/10/16  13:25:51   | D          
1234   | 13/10/16  17:31:50   | E          
4567   | 12/10/16  12:00:00   | B           
4567   | 12/10/16  12:06:13   | X
4567   | 13/10/16  12:25:00   | C
4567   | 13/10/16  12:26:19   | E
4567   | 14/10/16  13:20:22   | G
```

I want to transpose the dataset so I can get one row per person, per day which shows the end to end journey (so all route stages). I would also like to display the first datetime i.e. when the journey starts. The definition of a journey is:

- the  route stages must all be for the same person id, on the same day and within up to 3 mins of each other

In cases where there is just one letter in the route, I still want to display just the single route stage. There could be any number of route stages in the entire journey (although realistically it should not be more than 20).

I would like the dataset to look like the table below:

```
ID     |  Datetime            |   Journey   
------ | -------------------- | ------------   
1234   | 12/10/16  10:20:00   | A-B-C                  
1234   | 12/10/16  13:25:51   | D          
1234   | 13/10/16  17:31:50   | E          
4567   | 12/10/16  12:00:00   | B           
4567   | 12/10/16  12:06:13   | X
4567   | 13/10/16  12:25:00   | C-E
4567   | 14/10/16  13:20:22   | G
```

As my dataset is in MS SQL server, I would like to do the coding in this, however I don't know how to do this. Can anyone help?

I explored using a lead function with partition (by time), but when I have journeys with 3+ route stages, it got really messy and I couldn't look at time differences easily (especially when the time was null).

If this is not possible, I am happy to take suggestions on how to do this in R.

Thanks!

=====================================================

EDIT: 28/12/16

I opted for hrbrmstr's suggestion which worked really well (I had a file with 300k+ records). The code I used was:

```
read.csv(file="mydata.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")     %>%  

tbl_df() %>%

mutate(datetime=as.POSIXct(datetime, format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"))-> df

arrange(df, ID, datetime) %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
mutate(is_b=ifelse((datetime>=lag(datetime)) &
                   (datetime<=lag(datetime)+(3*60)), 0, 1),
     is_b=ifelse(is.na(is_b), 1, is_b),
     grp=cumsum(is_b)) %>%
group_by(ID, grp) %>%
summarise(starttime=min(datetime), Journey=paste0(Routestage, collapse="-"))-> output1 

write.csv(x=output1, "mydatanew.csv", row.names=TRUE, na="")
```

Comment: what's your dbms?

Comment: It's MS SQL server

Comment: The main key is using row_number() order by with a self left join back to the previous row grouped by id. I'd wrap it in a stored procedure in case extra steps are required.

Comment: What do you mean by a stored procedure, Keith John Hutchison?

Comment: create stored procedure mssql https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=create%20stored%20procedure%20mssql

Comment: Once you have a stored procedure you can add parameters ... like start date, end date, the number of minutes to determine if the nodes are in the same journey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided there are `dplyr` SQL transforms for some of the functions, this:

```
library(dplyr)

read.table(text="ID,Datetime,Routestage
1234,12/10/16  10:20:00,A
1234,12/10/16  10:21:22,B
1234,12/10/16  10:23:34,C
1234,12/10/16  13:25:51,D
1234,13/10/16  17:31:50,E
4567,12/10/16  12:00:00,B
4567,12/10/16  12:06:13,X
4567,13/10/16  12:25:00,C
4567,13/10/16  12:26:19,E
4567,14/10/16  13:20:22,G", header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  mutate(Datetime=as.POSIXct(Datetime, format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"))-> df

arrange(df, ID, Datetime) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(is_b=ifelse((Datetime>=lag(Datetime)) &
                     (Datetime<=lag(Datetime)+(3*60)), 0, 1),
         is_b=ifelse(is.na(is_b), 1, is_b),
         grp=cumsum(is_b)) %>%
  group_by(ID, grp) %>%
  summarise(Datetime=min(Datetime), Journey=paste0(Routestage, collapse="-"))
## Source: local data frame [7 x 4]
## Groups: ID [?]
## 
##      ID   grp            Datetime Journey
##   <int> <dbl>              <dttm>   <chr>
## 1  1234     1 2016-10-12 10:20:00   A-B-C
## 2  1234     2 2016-10-12 13:25:51       D
## 3  1234     3 2016-10-13 17:31:50       E
## 4  4567     1 2016-10-12 12:00:00       B
## 5  4567     2 2016-10-12 12:06:13       X
## 6  4567     3 2016-10-13 12:25:00     C-E
## 7  4567     4 2016-10-14 13:20:22       G
```

shld execute in-database. However, I'm fairly certain there's no `cumsum()` translation into the the `PARTITION` + `SUM()` idiom @vkp used, and it's unlikely there's a `paste0()` equivalent, to this might just be a local R solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this response. I have amended the code slightly to read in an excel spreadsheet (as the table is 1000s of rows), so the code looks like this...`install.packages("xlsx")
library(xlsx)

read.xlsx("MyData.xlsx", 1)     %>%

tbl_df()                                                  %>%
mutate(datetime=as.POSIXct(datetime, format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"))-> df`    when I run the code, it returns 'n/a' for the datetime field

Comment: a `dput()` of the data after the `tbl_df()` wld be helpful (in your original question)

Comment: I figured out the issue - the datetime wasn't in the right format so was not being read in correctly. I used your suggestion and it worked perfectly! I adapted slightly to read in a csv and output to a csv (as I need to do some further manipulation). Thank you so much for the response. I have posted the code I used in the edit above :-)

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to group records that are with in 3 minutes of each other for a given id. Use `lag` and some additional logic to get it.

Thereafter, get the first date for each group and use `STUFF` to concatenate the routes for the same group on to one row.

```
WITH grps
AS (SELECT
  id,
  dt,
  route_stage,
  SUM(col) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt) AS grp
FROM (SELECT
  t.*,
  CASE
    WHEN dt BETWEEN LAG(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt) AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 3, LAG(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt)) THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END col
FROM t) t)
SELECT DISTINCT
  id,
  MIN(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY id, grp) AS min_dt,
  STUFF((SELECT
    '-' + t1.route_stage
  FROM grps t1
  WHERE t1.id = t.id
  AND t1.grp = t.grp
  FOR xml PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS journey
FROM grps t
```

**[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/STGPK29311)**

Comment: Performance advice? remove the TYPE and .value call. this will turn the result to an implicit varchar return, and save a lot of needless overhead.

Comment: vkp, thanks so much for this - I follow the logic, except for the last section where you use stuff. I keep getting an error message as follows: 'Parse error at line: 25, column: 122: Incorrect syntax near 'FOR'.'. It doesn't seem to like the 'for xml path' bit. I am using visual studio 2013 if that helps?

Comment: which version of SQL server are you using? `[stuff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) works on sql server versions 2008 and beyond.

Comment: MS SQL server 2012. This is strange! When I try to run a very basic piece of code e.g.   select routestage from mytbl for xml path(''), type

Comment: MS SQL server 2012. This is strange! When I try to run a very basic piece of code e.g.   select routestage from mytbl for xml path(''), type                    I get an error message as above (incorrect syntax near for). I have also noticed that the word 'path' goes blue in the code which doesn't happen in your demo. It doesn't like this xml path line....

Comment: try this and check if it works ..`SELECT ',' + route_stage
FROM grps
FOR XML PATH ('')`  the error you are getting is because you must have omitted a `)` somewhere .

Comment: it still doesn;t work, I get the error: 'Parse error at line: 21, column: 36: Incorrect syntax near 'grps'.'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not so concise (dplyr may provide faster solutions) but with base packages here is the solution (replace "./data/41252090" with the path to the csv data file as such

```
ID,Datetime,Routestage
1234,12/10/16  10:20:00,A
1234,12/10/16  10:21:22,B
1234,12/10/16  10:23:34,C
1234,12/10/16  13:25:51,D
1234,13/10/16  17:31:50,E
4567,12/10/16  12:00:00,B
4567,12/10/16  12:06:13,X
4567,13/10/16  12:25:00,C
4567,13/10/16  12:26:19,E
4567,14/10/16  13:20:22,G
```

The code is:

```
dailypath <- function(datap = "./data/41252090") {
    data1 <- read.csv(datap, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
    data1[,2] <- as.POSIXct(strptime(data1[,2], "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"))
    ids <- unique(data1$ID)
    ID <- NULL
    Datetime <- NULL
    Routestage <- NULL

    for (i in ids) {
        dataid <- data1[data1$ID == i,]
        datesi <- unique(as.Date(dataid$Datetime))
        for (j in datesi) {
            dataiddate <- dataid[as.Date(dataid$Datetime) == j,]
            datetimes <- dataiddate$Datetime
            mint <- as.numeric(datetimes[-1]) - as.numeric(datetimes[-length(datetimes)]) > 180
            journeys <- c(1, cumsum(mint) + 1)

            for (z in unique(journeys)) {
                journey <- dataiddate[journeys == z,]
                datetime <- min(journey$Datetime)
                routes <- paste(journey$Routestage, sep = "-", collapse = "-")
                ID <- c(ID, i)
                Datetime <- c(Datetime, datetime)
                Routestage <- c(Routestage, routes)
            }
        }
    }
    summarydf <- data.frame(ID = ID, Datetime = as.POSIXct(Datetime, origin="1970-01-01"), Journey = Routestage)
    return(summarydf)
}
```

and it returns:

```
    ID            Datetime Journey
1 1234 2016-10-12 10:20:00   A-B-C
2 1234 2016-10-12 13:25:51       D
3 1234 2016-10-13 17:31:50       E
4 4567 2016-10-12 12:00:00       B
5 4567 2016-10-12 12:06:13       X
6 4567 2016-10-13 12:25:00     C-E
7 4567 2016-10-14 13:20:22       G
```